# Using global variable as default parameter

Tags: python

**a.py**

```
#!c:/Python27/python.exe -u

from connection import Connection
import globals

globals.server_ip = '192.168.0.1'
connection = Connection()
```

**globals.py**

```
#!c:/Python27/python.exe -u

server_ip = '127.0.0.1'
```

**connection.py**

```
import globals

class Connection:        
    def __init__(self, server_ip = globals.server_ip):
        print 'Connection is ' + server_ip + '\n'
```

I was expecting I will be getting `Connection is 192.168.0.1` being printed. But, instead, `Connection is 127.0.0.1` is being printed.

Unless I try to construct the connection by passing in the parameter explicitly (which is not something I wish to, as I am reluctant to make change any more on Connection with 0 parameter)

`connection = Connection(globals.server_ip)`

Why is this so? Is there any other techniques I can apply?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, server_ip=globals.server_ip):
```

The argument is bound when the method is created and not re-evaluated later.
To use whatever is the current value, use something like this:

```
def __init__(self, server_ip=None):
    if server_ip is None:
        server_ip = globals.server_ip
```

---

Btw, for exactly the same reason a function like this would be likely to not work as intended:

```
def foobar(foo=[]):
    foo.append('bar')
    return foo
```

In performance-critical code this behaviour can also be used to avoid global lookups of builtins:

```
def highspeed(some_builtin=some_builtin):
    # in here the lookup of some_builtin will be faster as it's in the locals
```